# How to prove or disprove the asymptotic normality of the following?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Let $\{X_{1},\ldots ,X_{n}\}$ be a sequence of dependent random variables. For $i,j \in [n]$, given

\begin{align}
 E[X_{i}] &= 0.\\
\text{Var}(X_{i}) &= \sigma^2 <  \infty.\\
\text{Cov}(X_{i}, X_{j}) &= 0, \quad i \neq j.
\end{align}

Can we say something about the asymptotic normality of $X_{1}+ \ldots+ X_{n}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Any help or lead would be highly appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/792522/66096